# How can I warp the border between two different sized monitors, so the mouse doesn't get stuck in the larger one?

Tags: macos, display, mouse

When the monitor on one side of the border has a resolution higher than the monitor on the other side, the mouse can only cross over to the other monitor at the part where their edges overlap, as in the configuration below.

[image: OSX Yosemite Display Arrangement Dialog]

This means that when the mouse is not in the overlapping area, for example in the upper area of the right monitor in the image, it can't cross over to the other monitor without moving to the overlapping area.

Is there a way to warp the border, so that the proportional position of the mouse on the departing side is converted to the same proportion on the arriving side?

Answer (score 1):

It's just not possible, I'm afraid.

Even with this setup, though I can move the mouse freely between the two screens, if I have a window tight to the top of the right hand screen, I must drop it far enough to clear the menu bar before it will drag to the left screen.

[image]